# Locally Compact Spaces: Separation Property

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space.

> Every compact set has a compact neighborhood base:
>   $$C\subseteq U:\quad N\subseteq U\quad(C\subseteq N^°)$$

My construction was contrary to Rudin's:
$$N_c\subseteq U:\quad C\subseteq\bigcup_{c\in C}N_c^°\implies C\subseteq N_1^°\cup\ldots N_n^°$$

But I needn't make use of the Hausdorff property; or did I miss something?

*(Hausdorff seems rather to guarantee that compact sets are closed.)*

Comment: It depends on which definition of [local compactness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) he’s using.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Aha, right he uses only the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is just to check off the thread.*

As Brian M. Scott rightly observed the problem is that Rudin uses a weaker definition.